# Use different SD Cards for Android app

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I am building an app for which I might have to read content from two or more different SD Cards. I will have the app on the device but the content on different cards. The user has to plug in different card to see some content and another one to see another. How do I code for this ? Do Sdcards have identifiers? I cant just say read from external storage or do a /mnt/sdcard since even though it ll work i wont know which card I am reading from. ON A related topic is this a good way to design or is it better to have different apps on different cards all together so the cards are whole on their own?

The main rationale here is I have a lot of data for one version of the app. Say I have 32 gb data and I have a 16gb sd card device. I ll need two sd cards for just the single version.

Comment: Can you please explain the rationale for using different SD Cards?

Comment: Maybe you should use some additional config file on a SD Card, that distinguishes information that is hold on a specific SD Card?

Comment: They make 32GB (and for devices which support SDXC, even 64GB) cards now.  Considering that on some phones (original moto droid for example) you have to remove the battery to remove the sdcard, the expense of a larger card seems far preferable to swapping cards.  Not to mention the ease of losing them.  Since you likely have a highly specialized application, if you really want to interchange storage media you might look at devices which can support removable usb sticks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree with @Rajesh, can you tell us more about why you'd want it on separate SD cards?

And I think Benjamin is right too, the only way that you have to do this really is to implement and enforce it yourself, by putting a specific (unique) file that you can check for each card

Comment: The main rationale here is I have a lot of data for one version of the app. Say I have 32 gb data and I have a 16gb sd card device. I ll need two sd cards for just the single version.

Comment: How is the data going to get on to the SD cards? I think your best bet is going to be using your own file that can tell the app which SD is which.